# Need Help Logical Question

Tags: contest-math

There are three small tanks of capacity 35 L, 56 L, 84 L. Lets Find what will be the biggest capacity of a container which will measure the oil in 3 tanks in exact whole numbers.

Ans=71.

Please Provide Solution and Explain.

Comment: I think it should be 7 not 71. Because HCF or GCD of three numbers is 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When words like biggest, highest and greatest are used. You have to find HCF.

HCF of 35 L, 56 L and 84 L is 7 L. So answer is 7 L.

In answer after 7 it's L not 1.

Comment: Does HCF stand for "highest common factor"?

Comment: Yes hcf stands for highest common factor.